# Finding all the :has_many relationship defined on a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, has-many

I have a model User that has defined in user.rb many relationships like

```
has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
... and others
```

How can I programmatically find all such relationships? That is I want to be able to do find all the child models like Post, Comment etc via Rails and not have to look at the user.rb file manually.

How can I do this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the underlying problem that you are trying to solve?  You're asking a totally valid question, but I'd like to know what the use case is...

Comment: @MarcTalbot: sure. I want to be able to delete all the children but not the parent itself. if I do a user.destroy, once all the children get deleted, the parent is deleted too. I don't want to delete the parent - I'd maybe stamp the user record itself with a status = inactive or something. Makes sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want to do is called "reflecting" -- whereby your software finds out more about itself, on the fly, at runtime.

In Rails, ActiveRecord supports this. See the [Reflection](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html) methods.

**Added** per the docs, you'd call

```
associations = User.reflect_on_all_associations(:has_many)
```

You'd get back an array of objects that would give you info about all of the has_many associations of your User class.